# How to drive a linear actuator in both directions

Tags: motor, relay, driver, actuator

I would like to drive in both directions my linear actuator (12VDC, 13A max).
My electronic board outputs two signals (obviously, I also have GND signal):

**Forward**: +12VDC (2A max)

**Backward**: +12VDC (2A max)

When I press the forward button, the forward output is +12V, on the contrary, when I press the backward button, I have +12V on the backward output line.

The battery for this system is an AGM battery, 12VDC, 200Ah.

I know that the correct way would be to use a driver, but it is expensive and I do not need lots of functions, I only need to open and close the actuator.

I was thinking to trigger two relays by using the forward and backward signals, but I can't figure out how to connect them in a correct way.

Can you give me some suggestions, please?

Comment: Swap the signals.

Comment: @Marko It seems that the OP understands this, from what I read it looks like they're after a way to do it using signals rather than buttons

Comment: @MarkoBuršič, I know that I can swap signals, but this is not the  solution I'm looking for. I need to use these two signals..

Comment: Is the use forward/reverse or forward/off/reverse?

Comment: The standard use is when actuator is in STOP mode. Sometimes it can go forward for few seconds or backward but it always returns in STOP mode.

Comment: Can you press both the forward and backward buttons at the same time? If so, what voltages appear on the output lines?

Comment: It is possible to press both buttons at the same time even if this is NOT a correct behavior. When this happens, I read +12VDC between forward and GND and +12VDC between backward and GND.

Comment: The problem is that i want to keep the linear actuator move forward or backward while one of the buttons is pressed and it should stop when I release the button.

Comment: @MarcusBarnet In that case, you could use an XOR gate in the circuitry to prevent forward and reverse being powered at the same time.

Comment: When you apply reverse voltage  at some speed you will have the generated voltage minus the reverse voltage and thus more current than start. Any switch used must be rated for the power lost and the repetition rate.

Answer (score 7):

Use an H-bridge. It is cheap and straightforward to build.

http://www.bristolwatch.com/k150/port4.htm

I use this for high current switching: http://www.bristolwatch.com/k150/pics1/mosfet_hb2.png

These N- and P-channel MOSFETs have a fairly low V_DS(ON) resistance, and don't run very hot at 2A. P = (I^2) x R = 4 x 0.8 = 3.2W for the IRF9630, less for the IRF630.

I don't personally like BJT transistors in H-bridges except to control the MOSFETs, but perhaps there are scenarios where they're better. If so, others may chime in with their cluebats.

Hope it helps.

Edit: the linked schematic is not for PWM (I used it for 12V actuators as well). Cost was low, <5USD

Comment: I do not need the PWM, I just need to make the linear actuator move forward and backward without controlling its speed. The H-bridge solution is the best one I can use, I guess.. the problem is that I need to realized a PCB in order to use the MOSFETs. Using relays would be faster, but it is dangerous since there is the short circuit problem..

Comment: @MarcusBarnet Just get some PTH, I've never used PCB. My circuits are never big enough to require it, and perfboard is fast.

Comment: A perfboard can support currents up to 13A?

Comment: @Marcus Is the "short circuit problem" something you've thought of yourself or do you have actual evidence of such an issue?

Comment: This is only my concern, I used relays in the past and I never had an issue like this, to be honest! But I was thinking that if a relay becomes old, a delay could generate a short circuit somehow..

Comment: @Marcus That's true if you use two separate relays, one for each line. If one fails then it can go quite wrong... However, if you use a DPST relay like Andy's answer the switching poles inside are linked mechanically so they can't actually cause a short circuit. [Here's a really good animation](http://iamtechnical.com/sites/default/files/spdt-relay.gif) that shows what I mean, that's an SPST, now imagine a relay that has two of those inside, that's a DPST relay Andy is talking about.

Comment: @Hayman, I answered below the Andy's message.

Answer (score 6):

> I was thinking to trigger two relays by using the forward and backward
>   signals, but I can't figure out how to connect them in a correct way.
>   Can you give me some suggestions, please?

Try this for a relay reverser: -

[image]

A motor is shown but that can be your linear actuator.

Contacts required in relay: two single pole changeover (or double pole, double throw).

You might need to put back-to-back zener diodes across the actuator to "catch" any back-emfs.

Comment: I've done this, with dismal results. Usually it works fine, but when it doesn't (switching time of my relay was 15ms) it shorts out the 12V line.

Comment: This was my worry since if there is a delay in the relay, a short-circuit may occur.. this would be dangerous for the batteries and the system..

Comment: @user400344 How are you shorting out your 12V line? I may be wrong but looking at the DPDT relay I have in my hand it's physically impossible for one side to fail and cause a short. Not to mention that the switching difference between the two poles is insignificant.

Comment: @Hayman I used an arduino and port registers to do the switching on a dualchannel 5V relay, to accomplish the same thing that OP is talking about. Occasionally there was a short and I had to unplug fast. Didn't use zener finesse though. The H-bridge has never caused me any problems. Please enlighten me if I was a stupid monkey.

Comment: @user400344 I think you're confused, what you probably used was one of [these modules?](https://micromechtronic.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/2-channel-relay-5v-600x600.jpg) which is two separate relays. Yes, these can have the problem you mention, if one relay is slower than the other or one fails then you will get a short circuit. The relay Andy mentions in his answer is a relay [like this one](http://media.digikey.com/Photos/Omron%20Elect%20Photos/G2R-PC.JPG), the poles in this relay are mechanically linked so they always switch together and not separately, so no short circuits possible.

Comment: I'm sorry guys may be I'm getting confused.. If I use a single DPST relay I will have only two poles to drive the coil (+12V, GND) as shown in the Andy's answer.
I have two signals: forward, backward and GND so how can I drive the relay's coil?

Comment: @MarcusBarnet use  a DP**D**T relay as in the answer. I've done this successfully, several times.

Comment: @Hayman Correct. The bizarre bit is that I have a lot of those 12V relays you linked to.

Comment: @Hayman I second that, I'll be using these DPDT relays more often now. Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisH I realise now I kept swapping between DPDT and DPST, **DPDT** is the correct relay as Chris points out

Comment: I saw the DPDT relay schematics and now I can understand your suggestions: you say to connect GND on the first terminal coil and both backward and forward signals to the second terminal coil. The problem is that i want to keep the linear actuator move forward or backward while one of the buttons is pressed and it should stop when I release the button. Can this be possible with a DPDT relay?

Comment: If you want to do this using a DPDT relay you'd have to put the switches in line with either \$V_{S}\$ or \$GND\$. I'll do a new design based on all the info from the comments

Answer (score 2):

Use two contactors with a interlocking mechanism. You will find such contactors in a electical specialized shops. There are also ready made kits, with motor protection and reversing contactors. Try to google: reversing contactor. This kind of contactor has the mechanical lock between them, preventing to be engage both of them at the same time - this would cause short circuit.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRv_LhhMofE

http://www.cesco.com/b2c/product/Schneider-Electric-LC2K0901B7-Reversing-Contactor/614180

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, the problem is that the contactor is expensive. A motor controller with short-circuit protection and over-current protection costs about 70 USD and it can drive my linear actuator without problems. I would like to avoid the contactors if possible..

Comment: @MarcusBarnet: DPDT relays like in Andy's message is even cheaper. Typically around US$3 each

Answer (score 2):

In response to the comments on both the question as well as Andy's answer I've decided to post my own answer.

From what I've gathered, you want the operation to be normally stationary. Then either forward or reverse but *only* while the button is pressed.

How the circuit below works, with no buttons pressed there is no positive voltage on the terminal of the relay, no voltage no motor movement, simple stuff.

When the REV button is pressed, it connects \$V_{S}\$ to the relay terminal. Now there is \$V_{S}\$ on your \$MOT-\$ and \$0V\$ on your \$MOT+\$. So your motor will move in reverse whilst the button is held.

When the FWD button is pressed, like before it still connects \$V_{S}\$ to the relay terminal. However, this time it also uses \$V_{S}\$ to saturate the NPN transistor which will cause current to flow through the relay coil and the relay will actuate changing the poles. Now you have \$V_{S}\$ on your \$MOT+\$ and \$0V\$ on your \$MOT-\$, so your motor will move forward whilst the button is held.

The purpose behind the diode on the FWD button line is so that when you press the REV button, it doesn't saturate the transistor, there will be an ~0.7V drop when your motor is running in the FWD direction but it shouldn't make much difference to the speed. Depending on your motor though, you will need quite a high current diode.

As for the transistor and base resistor values, without all the voltages and currents I can't really give any recommendation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fySkpZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: My understanding of the question is that the forward button outputs a signal. The reverse button outputs a separate signal. Both buttons can be pressed at the same time which results in 12 V being present on both signal lines. The signals are used to indicate direction, but are insufficient in current capability to drive the actuator.

Comment: Exactly, Andrew! The signal are used only as reference for the direction and they are not capable to directly drive the actuator since they outputs 2A at maximum.

Comment: @Hayman, your solution is great! I think I can use it without problems!

Comment: The base of the NPN transistor at the moment looks to me as if it can be 'floating' - as in disconnected from everything at least sometimes, which is probably undesirable, right?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it with just two relays and **no risk of short circuit.**

Instead of connecting your power source to the COM input on the relay, and the motor to your NO (Normally Open) and NC (Normally Closed) contacts, you reverse it.
Connect the + and - of your power source to NO and NC on the relay, and have the COM go to one of the contacts on your motor (see diagram). Do the same for the other contact on your motor with a second relay, but hook the +/- opposite from the first relay. This way the relay determines whether + or - will go to a given contact on the motor, but it can't send both at the same time.
So the worst case scenario is that you send hot to both contacts on the motor (or ground to both contacts) which shouldn't do anything.

And you gang the input line together on both relays so that they get triggered together.

(Keep in mind, with this wiring, there is no *off* state, just forward or reverse. But you could easily add this functionality by adding one more relay.)

[image]